# sound doesn't work in macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I have a macbook pro and yesterday the sound just stopped working.I was funny cause I turn it off and tried and cool it down cause I thought that it's been so hot. after that it worked but after a few minutes it just stopped working.

Now there is no start up sound. there is no input and output device in system preferences.and No, there is not any red light. I also tried command option R P.

I don't know what to do. help me guys.

Comment: Just to be sure - you don't have mute on do you? :-) (the F10 key)

Comment: I'm having this problem right now? How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue several months ago. After many hours of unsuccessful troubleshooting, I brought it to genius bar at apple store and was told to reinstall system software. It solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

Go to Audio Midi Setup and switch the Output Format away from 44.1khz and back again.

And I once had to uninstall Elmedia Player for Mac (esp. empdaemon) to prevent sudden loss of sound.

http://mac.eltima.com/media-player.html

(To prevent your MacBook from overheating esp. on very hot days have a look at smcFanControl or FanControl, http://www.lobotomo.com/products/FanControl/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a hardware issue. Depending on your resources you could try running a separate install of OSX on the machine from an external drive to see if the problem persists. You could even go as far as doing a reinstall of the OS.

However, I would recommend taking it into Apple themselves or an authorised service provider. They'll be able to tell you exactly what's failing and how much it'd cost to fix (assuming you're out of warranty).

Depending on which generation your machine is, and then which component has failed, this could be cheap (it could be the audio/IO board if machine is a 2006 to early 2008 Macbook Pro), but is likely going to be a logic board issue - which is usually not an economically viable fix due to silly costs.